# dynamodb "start key" query or scan

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How to make query which shows the next items of "starting key" for example start_key="b" should display

```
c
d
e
f
```

I am using node.js and AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

Comment: so what do you mean by the "next items of starting_key"? Do you mean on the basis of the time they were inserted into dynamoDB or just sorted order of the start_key ?

Comment: Also, what is your data model? Is this "key" a sort key and all these items are in a single partition? If so, the answer to your question is simple - use KeyConditionExpression of "key >= :start_key". But I don't know if I should post this as an answer, because I'm not sure I understand the question...

Comment: "key >= :start_key" works but only for numbers , thanks for pointing that out